# outlier labels incorrectly assigned with ggplot2 box plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to label outliers in a ggplot box plot with the name of the subject for which outlying data were observed.

I have proceeded by creating a simple function to identify outliers:

```
is_outlier <- function(x) {
  return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))
}
```

And then the `safe_ifelse` workaround to get `ifelse` to function properly with factors.

```
safe.ifelse <- function(cond, yes, no) {
  class.y <- class(yes)
  if (class.y == "factor") {
    levels.y = levels(yes)
  }
  X <- ifelse(cond,yes,no)
  if (class.y == "factor") {
    X = as.factor(X)
    levels(X) = levels.y
  } else {
    class(X) <- class.y
  }
  return(X)
}
```

From here, I have run data through a `dplyr` pipeline to produce the plot data at https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pcuuclxiqw1va1/data.csv?dl=0

`library(dplyr)
data<-subset(data,data$variable1!='NA')`

```
p1<-
  data %>%
  group_by(season,location) %>%
  mutate(outlier=safe.ifelse(is_outlier(variable1),subject,as.numeric(NA))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(season),y=variable1))+
  geom_boxplot()+         
  facet_wrap(~location,nrow=2)+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  geom_text(aes(label=outlier),na.rm=TRUE,hjust=1.5,size=2.5)
```

While outliers are correctly identified, labeling does not work as it should. Rather than getting subject-specific outlier labels, three levels of the `subject` factor are printed repeatedly and erroneously (and seemingly randomly). Labeling outliers by their numerical values (i.e. by changing `subject` to `variable1` in the `safe_ifelse` function) do not cause problems.

I assume I am missing something obvious here - perhaps someone could kindly indicate where I am going wrong?

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to subset your data in geom_text, to show uniquely the text on the outliers.

```
data <-data %>%
  group_by(season,location) %>%
  mutate(outlier=safe.ifelse(is_outlier(variable1),subject,as.numeric(NA)))

p1 <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(season),y=variable1))+
  geom_boxplot()+         
  facet_wrap(~location,nrow=2)+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  geom_text(data = data[!is.na(data$outlier),],aes(label=subject),hjust=1.5,size=2.5)
```